# App (swift) can not show the core location authorization alert

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am writing a swift app follow the tutorial in the ‘The iOS Apprentice’,at this step, I want to use the getButton in the scene to show the authorization alert to access the GPS but it did not work.I checked the codes and also modify the info.plist(added the NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription) but still not works.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class CurrentLocationViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var latitudeLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var longitudeLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var addressLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tagButton:UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var getButton:UIButton!

@IBAction func getLocation() {
    let authStatus:CLAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if authStatus == .NotDetermined {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        return
    }

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

// MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager!,didFailWithError error:NSError!) {
    print("didFailWithError \(error)")
}

func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager!,didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]!) {
    let newLocation = locations.last as! CLLocation
    print("didUpdateLocations \(newLocation)")
}
```

Comment: Double check your plist key.  Perhaps it is just a typo in your question. It should be `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageKey` but I think your real problem is the return after the requestWhenInUseAuthorization. This will result in your delegate not being set

Comment: And if the delegate isn't set, you can't know when the user has approved.  Moreover, you're trying to `startUpdatingLocation` even if the authStatus isn't one of the approved statuses... and you're missing the didChangeAuthStatus delegate method...